# SQL user login access to views only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have given a user a login to the SQL sever for a selected database with permission on data reader. I would like to know is it possible for me to only give them access to certain view using that login, if so how would i go about doing this

Answer (score 2):

After creating the SQL Server Login add database user you can give that user rights to a single object using:

```
GRANT SELECT ON my_view TO my_user
```

As roryap said, you can't give that user the data reader role because that gives them select on everything.

Comment: but what if that view is querying data against other tables?

Comment: @JingHe With views, the user that creates the view must have access to the underlying tables for the view to compile.  Then for the view to work for any other user, they only need grants to the view, not the underlying tables.  This allows users to only have access to certain curated data without ever granted them full access to the underlying data.

Comment: I got it. It is done by the owernship chain. The owner of the view and the owner of the base table must be same, then the user with only access to the view can actually see the data from the base table by querying the view. If the base table is in a different database (but within the same SQL Server instance), we also need to enable the cross-db ownership chain to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't give them the data reader role because that gives them access to select from any table, etc.; rather you could define the permissions explicitly.  You would do this in SSMS, for example, by opening the properties for the object (e.g. view, in your case) and selecting "Permissions" then entering the individual permissions there.